# Splitting timespan when overlapping

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting, timespan

I have multiple TXT files which represents time spans in seconds for selected portions of videos. For example, 1.23-5.45.

I want to use these time spans to take these portions of multiple videos and create a single video with all the portions.

I'm parsing all of these TXT files into an array of KeyValue pairs list:

```
List<KeyValuePair<Double, Double>>[] TagsOfSeconds= new List<KeyValuePair<Double, Double>>[]()
```

Each index of array element represents a TXT file. And each element is a a KeyValue pair list where each pair is the start-end of the seconds time span.

My requirement is to parse these TXT files and split the time spans to segments of 5 seconds (5 is an example, the segment value will be provided by the user) and order the segments with priority to segment with the smallest value (happened before other segments) and if two are equal, take the one that is first in the  TagsOfSeconds array.

Here is an illustration. Segment order is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
I created the following structure to keep track of the portions parsed from the text files:

```
public struct PortionInfo
   {
      public Double Start, End;
      public int VideoIndex, PortionIndex;
      public Double PortionLength;
   }
```

Here is my code for ordering the loaded segments based on the start time span and TXT file index:

```
private void OrderVideoPortions(List<KeyValuePair<Double, Double>>[] videoPortionslist)
  {
     videoPortionsOrder = new List<PortionInfo>(); //videoPortionsOrder.Sort()
     for(int i=0;i< videoPortionslist.Length;i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < videoPortionslist[i].Count; j++)
        {
           PortionInfo currentPortionInfo = new PortionInfo();
           currentPortionInfo.VideoIndex = i;
           currentPortionInfo.PortionIndex = j;
           currentPortionInfo.Start = videoPortionslist[i][j].Key;
           currentPortionInfo.End = videoPortionslist[i][j].Value;
           currentPortionInfo.PortionLength = currentPortionInfo.End - currentPortionInfo.Start;
           videoPortionsOrder.Add(currentPortionInfo);
        }
     }
     videoPortionsOrder.Sort(SortAscending);
  }



public static int SortAscending(PortionInfo p1, PortionInfo p2)
  {
     int returnVal = p1.Start.CompareTo(p2.Start);
     if (returnVal == 0)
     {
        return p1.VideoIndex.CompareTo(p2.VideoIndex);
     }
     else
        return returnVal;
  }
```

Now I have to generate the segments from the sorted list.

Can any one help me please to achieve this? I just want help or guidance on determining the intersections and segments.

Comment: It looks like you've solved the problem -- what remains to be done?

Comment: I'm able to sort the tags from the TXT files but i need to split them to smaller segments and create something similar to what is shown in the illustration

Comment: Can't you just round each time to the nearest 5s, then create each segment inside a loop that runs (endTime - startTime) / 5 times?

Comment: I think that won't work because the time segments can be as long as 400 seconds and I want to keep track on the timespans when they intersect or one of them precede the others.

Comment: I see you have now solved the problem, but generating 400/5=80 segments would not be a problem, and you can easily track which segment precedes the others by first doing the sorting as before, and then proceeding through the sorted list, adding each 5s chunk beginning at some time i to the (i/5)-th linked list in an array of totalTime/5 linked lists.  The first item in the list will be the 5s chunk that came first in the order, i.e. that precedes all other items in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and for trying. I think in some way my implementation is similar to what you are describing. In the portions list (large segments that need to be chunked) I'm looping through them and generating a new list with the chunks size I want, then modifying the original chunk size in the portions list and re-sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the PortionInfo Structure to have constructor and a bool Active that is set automatically to true when the structure is created.

```
private void CreateFinalSegments(List<PortionInfo> orderedVideoPortions)
      {
         int segmentSize = int.Parse(_txtTimeSegments.Text);
         int extrSegmentDuration = int.Parse(_txtExtraDurationAllowed.Text);
         PortionInfo currentPortion = new PortionInfo();
         finalSegments = new List<PortionInfo>();
         if (_txtExtraDurationAllowed.Text == "0" || _txtTimeSegments.Text == "0")
         {
            return;//Check that still needs to be handled
         }
         else
         {
            for (int i=0;i< orderedVideoPortions.Count;i++)
            {
               if (orderedVideoPortions[i].Active)
               {
                  if (orderedVideoPortions[i].PortionLength <= (segmentSize + extrSegmentDuration))
                  {
                     finalSegments.Add(orderedVideoPortions[i]);
                     currentPortion = orderedVideoPortions[i];
                     currentPortion.Active = false;
                     orderedVideoPortions[i]=currentPortion ;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     currentPortion = orderedVideoPortions[i];
                     finalSegments.Add(new PortionInfo(currentPortion.Start, currentPortion.Start+ segmentSize, currentPortion.VideoIndex, currentPortion.PortionIndex));
                     currentPortion.Start += segmentSize;
                     currentPortion.PortionLength = currentPortion.End - currentPortion.Start;
                     orderedVideoPortions[i] = currentPortion;
                     orderedVideoPortions.Sort(SortAscending);
                     i = 0;//Note: Needs to be rechecked because --i should be enough.
                  }
               }
            }
            Application.DoEvents();
            _lblStatus.Text = "Video segments generated. Now Working on generating final video";
         }
      }
```